# \tableofcontents from \part commands in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, parts

I am not able to generate the table of contents made of all the parts (declared by `\part` command) of my Beamer presentation. While sections of each part are listed easily, there is no hint in the Beamer user guide how to use `\tableofcontents` to generate the list of parts. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've left away the fancy bits (i.e. routing it all through templates, making hyperlinks out of it, go wild in `\beamer@partintoc!`), and the part names still won't show in the ordinary `\tableofcontents`. Oh, and since you can only have one `\AtBeginPart`, be careful not to overwrite this one.

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginPart{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@partintoc{\the\c@part}{\beamer@partnameshort}{\the\c@page}}%
}
%% number, shortname, page.
\providecommand\beamer@partintoc[3]{%
  \ifnum\c@tocdepth=-1\relax
    % requesting onlyparts.
    \makebox[6em]{PART #1:} #2
    \par
  \fi
}
\define@key{beamertoc}{onlyparts}[]{%
  \c@tocdepth=-1\relax
}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[onlyparts]
  \end{frame}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Ulrich! Your code did solve the issue.

Comment: @Tomik: You're welcome. (You're also welcome to mark your question as sufficiently resolved by ticking the checkbox to the left if you feel it is appropriate.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: thank you for this solution. How would I go about to also have a `part*` command (such that certain parts don't appear in the part ToC)?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz this really solved my problem.  I still want to go wild and do the fancy bits :-)

Comment: How to print the `part` counter in Roman?

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the beamer documentation, p. 98:

> If you give a long talk (like a lecture), you may wish to break up your talk into several parts. Each such part acts like a little “talk of its own” with its own table of contents, its own navigation bars, and so on.

So I guess there is no "built-in" way to create a table of contents spanning several parts in beamer. IMO, you should reorganize your presentation so that former parts become sections and former sections subsections. (As for former subsections, p. 34 of the documentation states "Do not use subsubsections, they are evil", but you could even ignore that.)

Comment: I obeyed exactly this recommendation from the manual.  I use a master document and include every part by `\include` due to flexibility reasons. Like @Tomik I think, I should do an outline overview about the different parts I will talk about.  On every part, I automatically insert a frame with the detailed table of content of that part, as mentioned in your quote.  So the only thing missing was the automatic generated outline for `\part`.  Thanks to @UlrichSchwarz this was solved. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since beamer doesn't directly support parts in the table of contents, I would simply use an `itemize` environment to print out the list of parts.

If you really wish to copy the comfortable `\tableofcontents` way, you may build a separate TOC file for that using `\addtocontents` (could be done with `\AtBeginPart{\addtocontents...}`) and process it, similar to `\beamer@tableofcontents` in beamerbasetoc.sty. But that requires some programming, you may decide if it's worth the effort for just one document. Extensive presentations with many parts requiring a content frame, besides the existing sectioning structure, might not be very common.

Comment: I did the same. Yet I am thinking about a more elegant solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this requires some programming... I'll edit above.