# Include the list of parts and their sections in a global tableofcontents of beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm using beamer to produce a long presentation with several parts.

Is there any way to generate a global TOC which should contains all the parts and their sections ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\AtBeginPart{%
    \frame{\partpage}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section Out-one}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{section Out-two}\begin{frame}\end{frame}


\part{Introduction}
    \section{section I-one}
        \subsection{subsection I-one}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
    \section{section I-two}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\part{chapter two}
    \section{section one}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
    \section{section two}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
    \section{section three}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does one of the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tableofcontents-from-part-commands-in-beamer) solve your problem?

Comment: No, since what I need is a toc with a depth goes from parts to sections.

Answer (score 1):

If there are not too many parts, a manual approach can be considered:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents

    \hskip-1.8em\structure{\hyperlink{Navigation4}{Introduction}}
    \tableofcontents[part=1]

    \hskip-1.8em\structure{\hyperlink{Navigation6}{chapter two}}
    \tableofcontents[part=2]  
\end{frame}

\section{section Out-one}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{section Out-two}\begin{frame}\end{frame}


\part{Introduction}

    \section{section I-one}
        \subsection{subsection I-one}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
    \section{section I-two}\begin{frame}\end{frame}


\part{chapter two}

    \section{section one}\begin{frame}2\end{frame}
    \section{section two}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
    \section{section three}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]